# Is this the right equation for this 3D surface?

Tags: 3d, surfaces

Is $\frac{\sin \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$ the right equation for this surface? I am confused what $z$ is doing in there (unless this is an implicit equation). I get something fairly similar looking if I omit it [in Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20sin%28sqrt%28x%5E2%2by%5E2%29%29/sqrt%28x%5E2%2by%5E2%29%20for%20x%20in%20-15%20to%2015), though it's hard to compare.

Also, does it have a proper name?

[image: 3D Surface]

Comment: Its proper name is [$\operatorname{sinc}(r)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function) where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it is not the (four-dimensional) graph of the function $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by 
$$f(x,y,z)=\frac{\sin(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},$$
but rather a slice of it; that is, choose some value $z=c$, and this graph is the graph of the function $g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$g(x,y)=\frac{\sin(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+c^2})}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+c^2}}.$$
Choosing different values of $c$ varies the graph; here is an animation of the graph of $g$ as $c$ goes from $0$ to $8$:

[image]

```
listofplots = {}; For[c = 0, c <= 40, c++, AppendTo[listofplots, 
  Plot3D[Sin[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + (c/5)^2]]/ Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + (c/5)^2], 
    {x, -15, 15}, {y, -15, 15}, PlotPoints -> 40, PlotRange -> {-0.2, 0.2}]]]

Export["animation.gif", listofplots, "DisplayDurations" -> {0.25}]
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense!

Comment: Go U of C math!

Comment: Haha thanks, glad I could help :)